# Create static library in iOS with selected files

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries

I have a library with lot of different components which are not depended on each other. I know i can create a static library and include it in a project. But is there a way I can select only particular files to be bundled into a static library. 
I have to handover the project to the client and I dont want to give them everything. 
Any idea ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a specific target which only include the selected files, and build this target into a static library.

Comment: Oh ok so I can created targets based on projects may be and select files that i need and then make static library of it. That sounds like a good idea. I will try it out. Thanks